# Issue with mounting Google drive with colab

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

Following code worked fine for mounting google drive with colab until yesterday. But it is not working today ( January 20). It shows the error shown below. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

`from google.colab import drive drive._mount('/content/drive')`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

change

```
drive._mount('/content/drive')
```

to

```
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```